# How can I apply this function to all elements with the same ID, not just the first?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, apply

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#coiso").addClass("four");
    });
</script>


<div id="coiso">1</div>
<div id="coiso">1</div>
<div id="coiso">1</div>
<div id="coiso">1</div>
<div id="coiso">1</div>
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pedro_Pombo/pC2Bj/149/)

Comment: Your divs have no names, they have [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#id)s, which should be unique within a document. Use [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#class) attribute to group HTML elements.

Comment: [Fixed demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pC2Bj/150/)

Comment: If you really need to use id's you could use :first selector like I used http://jsfiddle.net/8Xgbd/ but classes are way better in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"id" is supposed to be unique.  This is how I had solved a similar problem.

```
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div[data-id]").addClass("four")
     });
  </script>

<div id="coiso" data-id="">1</div>
<div id="coiso1" data-id="">2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's right, an id is indeed supposed to be unique. That's a bad pratice, I advice you to respect the standard.

With a class, in JavaScript, you can do the same thing with something like this :

```
var Elements = document.getElementsByClassName('NameClass');
```

With [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/), I don't know if a similar method exist. If it's the case, you'll find it in his doc on his website.